# Prevent automatically entering the room on startup

Tags: inform7

I want to give the player a chance to select a few options on game startup, such as their name.

The only problem is that the game insists on putting the player into the first room immediately and print the room name and description. That's not interesting for the player yet, though.

How can I prevent Inform 7 from automatically putting the player into the first room, or at least suppress the room name and description printing at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found:

```
The initial room is a room.
The first rule for printing the name of a room:
    if the player is in the initial room:
        do nothing;
    otherwise:
        continue the action.
```